# Why Doesn't Parent Jpanel with two Jpanels only showing the first Show itself without its Two Child Jpanels?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a `JPanel` with two more `JPanel`s, however, at the time, *when I'm going to show up the main `JPanel`, it only shows the first `Jpanel` on the main `Jpanel`.*

With the following example, you'll understand the question better:

I want something like this:

[image: Figure 1]

The two different things that I want to do works fine; even so, it does not, if I try to put them on the same `JPanel`.

*On the first `JPanel`, I want to add a `JFileChooser`, and in the other part, I want to add a `Drag & Drop TextArea`.*

I'm trying to do the mentioned things in above with this bunch of code, and only shows the first `Jpanel`. ***What I'm missing?***

I've created a `Main Jpanel`:

```
JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Then, I've created two `Jpanel`s to put them inside of the `Main Jpanel`:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JButton button = new JButton("Selecciona el arxiu .txt");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:/Users/Joan/Desktop/");
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            SelectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            //Amb el SelectedFile.getName(); Sabem el nom del arxiu.
            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                String sCurrentLine;
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SelectedFile));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
panel1.add(button);
```

And the second `Jpanel` looks like:

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setBackground(Color.red);
panel2.add(
    new JLabel("Drop a list from your file chooser here:"),
    BorderLayout.NORTH
);
ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setBackground(Color.white);
panel2.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

dt = new DropTarget(ta, this);
```

At the time, I want to put those two `Jpanel`s inside of the `Main Jpanel`. I do by this way. Then, I put it visible to show up:

```
container.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
container.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
container.setVisible(true);
```

But, the problem is for when I try to launch the program, it only shows the first `Jpanel (Jpanel1)`, and the other `Jpanel`s don't.

***What I'm doing wrong or what I've misunderstood?***

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. This small test program should if possible avoid file I/O.

Comment: when i run this code (with 'container' JPanel inside ad hoc created JFrame, it seems ok, the frame is divided into two JPanels(with button and red one). I dont't see the problem

Comment: I'm trying to add on my Jpanel2 the `dt`, because I can't add this DropTarget inside

Comment: If you're still stuck, and if the current answer does not provide the answer that you seek, then please re-read the links I've provided. The posted program should be small, but self-contained, meaning we can compile and run it un-altered, and without requirement of outside files or dependencies. You're still posting a snippet of code, nothing that we can run without ourselves putting in the effort to create the minimal program. We shouldn't be able to solve this because we put in more effort than you to solve it, but rather because we're able to see your mistake. Please help us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I explained step by step what I've tried, it's not a correct question?

Comment: It's not a matter of "correct" or not, and your step-by-step description does nothing for me since because you don't know yet what's causing the problem, and because of this, you're leaving out whatever it is that underlies the issue. For me, it's a matter of, *can I reproduce the problem with the code provided*. Again, if Jack's answer is what you need, then we're done. If not, and you want folks to fully understand your problem then again read the links and create and post your minimal runnable program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `BoxLayout` on your container you might want to try using a `GridLayout` instead.

```
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
```

then just this to add them:

```
container.add(panel1);
container.add(panel2);
```

**Edit:**

Full example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Side {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame");
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.red);

        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        container.add(panel1);
        container.add(panel2);

        frame.getContentPane().add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Skizo I added a full example showing this method should work. As commented on your question you should have a fully runnable example like that if you want proper/good help.

Comment: Okay, it works, but how can I add on my Jpanel2 the `dt`? `dt` is --> `static DropTarget dt;`